# Tags not completely hidden when used in spoilers

Tags: bug, tags, design, spoilers

> I think I discovered a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Tags like [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) are not completely hidden when used in spoilers. It seems not to be browser-related; I checked Safari and Chrome on Mac, and IE on Windows.

For future reference, this is how it looked like at the moment of posting:

[image]